# How can get access to type FormData in a CodeIgniter Controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$("#registry").click(function () {

 var data = new FormData();
  data.append('nombre', $("#name").val());
  data.append('apellido_paterno', $("#last_name").val());
  data.append('apellido_materno', $("#last_name_m").val());
  data.append('correo', $("#email").val());
  data.append('contrasena', $("#password").val());

  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'index.php/home/registry',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache : false,
    processData: false
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $("#error").html(response);
  });
});
```

I use FormData to apply the form validation but then i will save this data in the database, how i can get the values to insert they in the database?

Comment: You would do it the [same way](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html) you would do if you were submitting a form without AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the error was due to the ajax configuration.

Explanation: each type of data received as response (string, html, object, array, json) requires a special configuration. The documentacion for it, is in the following link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/